# Проблема с GreenDroid

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток! При использовании greendroid-a столкнулось с такой проблемой: приложение падает при пролистывании списка. Лог:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dctua.vkontakte/com.dctua.vkontakte.news.post.NewsPostActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/list. Make sure other views do not use the same id.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1797)
    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:682)
    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:346)
    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
    at greendroid.app.GDTabActivity.addTab(GDTabActivity.java:207)
    at greendroid.app.GDTabActivity.addTab(GDTabActivity.java:187)
    at com.dctua.vkontakte.news.NewsActivity.onCreate(NewsActivity.java:30)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    ... 11 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/list. Make sure other views do not use the same id.
    at android.view.View.onRestoreInstanceState(View.java:9963)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:9939)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2318)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2324)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2324)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2324)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2324)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:9917)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1600)
    at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:906)
    at greendroid.app.GDActivity.onRestoreInstanceState(GDActivity.java:136)
    at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:878)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1100)
    at and
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Как эту проблему можно решить?
З.Ы. id листов уже пробовал переименовывать - не помогло, приложение всё равно вылетает.

**Update** Проблема решена. Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: код и разметку приложите. Посмотрите также issues GreenDroid-а на гитхабе. А вообще, насколько я помню, либа уже устаревает, ибо автор ее не поддерживает. По крайней мере последние коммиты были в прошлом году.

Comment: код и разметку добавил; знаю,что либа устаревает,но данном этапе отказаться от неё,увы,не могу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подозреваю что:

1. Проблема может быть в том, что везде идентификатор списков андроидный(android:list) - ваш К.О. Такие идентификаторы нужны, когда ваш активити наследуется от ListActivity, чтобы система сама могла найти список в разметке.
2. Поэтому, наследоваться наверное нужно от GDListActivity. Непонятно, то ли вы назвали свой класс также, то ли подставили код из GreenDroid-а.
3. Наверное также стоит наследоваться не от TabActivity, а от GDTabActivity.

Вообщем, проверьте везде наследование классов, чтобы было от библиотечных классов. Поиграйтесь с названием идентификаторов для списков. Не забывайте чистить(Clean) проект.

Comment: в том то и дело,что у меня все активити наследуются как раз-таки от библиотечного GDTabActivity, а GDListActivity по сути нигде у меня и не используется

Comment: хотя вру: некоторые активити наследуются от BaseLisActivity

Comment: исправил наследование - приложение всё равно падает

Comment: исключение тоже?

Comment: заметил такую особенность - приложение падает только в том случае,когда я долистываю до конца списка